# Does Jest swallow console.log statements? Is there a way to change this?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Does Jest swallow `console.log` output?

```
// __tests__/log.test.js

it('logs', () => {
  console.log('hey') // expect to see "hey" printed in terminal
})

// terminal output
$ jest --forceExit
PASS  __tests__/log.test.js
✓ logs (1ms) # where's "hey"?
```

The main reason I care is that I'm writing some async `beforeAll` and `afterAll` stuff, and I want to use console.log statements to debug the order of events.

Comment: `--useStderr` worked for me for version `v22.4.2` https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--usestderr https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.log statements output nothing at all in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest)

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441).

With Node 10.7.0 and Jest 23.4.1, adding `verbose: false` to the jest config ([per this suggestion](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-286248619)) worked for me.

**Edit**

Now that I've gone to Jest 23.6 I also need to pass `TERM=dumb` as an environment variable, per Tamlyn's answer.

Answer (score 12):

> **Update**: this issue should be fixed [as of Jest 24](https://jestjs.io/blog/2019/01/25/jest-24-refreshing-polished-typescript-friendly#fixing-old-pain).

Another partial solution to the [current bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-416086964) affecting tests in `--watch` mode is to pass `TERM=dumb` as an environment variable.

```
TERM=dumb jest --watch
```

This has a small price in that it no longer clears the console before each test run so you have to scroll to see the results.

Comment: where do you add this TERM = dumb ?

Comment: You write it in the terminal, before the jest command, just as shown above.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that I was using `jest --forceExit`. Jest's logging model saves all the logs and spits them out later. `--forceExit` causes the process to bail before it reaches the spit-out-logs point.

Comment: I am having this issue without using `--forceExit`. =/ Any advice?

Comment: I am not using the `forceExit` setting, and I am still seeing jest swallow console statements.

Comment: Not sure what version of node you're both on but I have the same problem and it seems to be a known issue on node 7.3. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441

Comment: happens also with the `--bail, -b` option

Comment: Interesting find, thank you! As an alternative to removing forceExit you can also follow up your console.log with something like `await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 100 ) );` (as long as you're using an async function on a supported Node version, that is)

Answer (score 4):

I found a work around, despite the fact that sadly neither `TERM=dumb`, nor `verbose: false` nor upgrading to version 24 worked (I'm on 24.9). Just spy on the console, and you can see the results. Set it up with this:

`const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log')`

And then view the calls after running your tests using:

`consoleSpy.mock.calls[0][0]`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `--verbose` to the Jest arguments.

*This worked for me.*