# Console.log statements output nothing at all in Jest

Tags: jestjs, console.log

`console.log` statements output nothing at all in Jest. This was working for me yesterday, and all of sudden, it's not working today. I have made zero changes to my config and haven't installed any updates.

I'm not using the `--forceExit` option. Still seeing this issue.

Comment: This might answer, for some use cases at least: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190964/3088045

Answer (score 225):

Jest suppresses the console log message by default. In order to show the console log message, set silent option to false at the command line

set `--silent=false`  in the command line:

`npm run test -- --silent=false`

Comment: I vote for this one! Also search your code/command for the text `--SILENT` as there are so many different places with `jest` where this can be added, if you can't find any `silent` parameter then you should see logging.

Comment: even after using this flag, in watch mode, when tests are re-triggered, console logs are not emitted by jest

Answer (score 134):

You can run both options together like this `--watch --verbose false` if you want to also be watching the files and see the output.

for one time runs just do `--verbose false`

Comment: Note that the order of options matter. For example, if you use -t, you need to put --verbose false before the -t: `jest --verbose false -t my-test`

Comment: This answer is incorrect for Jest 27. `verbose` is related to how the test outputs pass/fail results. `silent` is for suppressing console output. https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--silent

Comment: this (`--verbose false`) doesn't work for me, I still don't see the console.log statements output

Comment: Nobody else thinks it's weird that to get _more_ output you have to set `verbose` mode to `false`?

Comment: YES, ITS WEIRD.

Comment: no it's not weird. it's super weird.

Answer (score 102):

This is a pretty old question and still there's no accepted answer. However, none of the suggested solutions worked for me (settings like --silent --verbose etc.). The main problem is that Jest changes the global `console` object. So, the easiest solution is to not use the global `console` object.

Instead import dedicated log functions from the console module and work with those:

```js
import { error } from "console";

error("This is an error");
```

As easy as that.

Comment: worked for me but I had to add `// @ts-ignore` above the import

Comment: The only solution that works for me, thank you! I did `import { log } from 'console'`, and use `log` instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Since JEST redefines the global console object, this is the only workaround. Works perfectly.

Comment: Simple. Works (in Jest 29). +10 if I could.

Comment: Or use a dedicated logging module...

Comment: One-liner:`require('console').error('hello jest');`

Answer (score 74):

As per comment on https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441,

Try setting verbose: false (or removing it) in the jest options in package.json.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you have `--verbose` in your command line flags you need to remove that as well. I thought this answer was incorrect until I realized that. Thanks.

Also, the relevant comment is here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441#issuecomment-286248619

Comment: Removing `"verbose": true` didn't solve it for me, I had to change it to false `"verbose": false`, which seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: In my case there was a `--silent` flag in the package.json file, had to remove it in order to see the console.log messages

Comment: This answer is incorrect  for Jest 27. `verbose` is related to how the test outputs pass/fail results. `silent` is for suppressing console output. https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--silent

Answer (score 33):

Try using `console.debug()` instead.

Run `console.debug('Message here', yourValueHere)` inside test function and it should show in the console output when running test script. You can verify if it works using `Ctrl+F` and find *Message here* in the standard output.

This does the trick of showing output in the console, while it is not an answer quite on how to use `console.log` I understand.

I am running `@testing-library/jest-dom` and `jest-junit 12.0.0` as devDependencies.
`jest-junit` has a minimal configuration of

```
  "jest-junit": {
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  },
```

in `package.json`. This is mainly to configure coverage reporting.
jest is configured like this:

```
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)",
      "!**/utilities.ts",
    ],
```

Answer (score 21):

One of the potential reason that logging is not printing is due to `console.log` has been mocked. Something as below

```js
// jest-setup.js
global.console = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  log: jest.fn(), // console.log are ignored in tests
  // log: console.log,

  // Keep native behaviour for other methods, use those to print out things in your own tests, not `console.log`
  error: console.error,
  warn: console.warn,
  info: console.info,
  debug: console.debug,
};
```

```js
// package.json
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect",
      "<rootDir>/src/config/jest-setup.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}"
    ]
  },
```

This is commonly used if you wish to disable `console.log` in `jest`

Comment: I've seen `global.console = { log: process.env['JEST_VERBOSE'] ? console.log : jest.fn(), };` in some projects. I think it's a better way to control the console output.

Answer (score 19):

Check for your command line flags in `package.json` to see that you don't have `--silent` in there.

Answer (score 17):

in addition to `--verbose` option which can cause this as mentioned, be aware that the `--watch`  may also cause this bug.

Answer (score 17):

If using Webstorm with Jest configuration, click on the file name instead of the test name.

[image: Webstorm Jest panel]

Comment: That is the case for not just webstorm, but any jetbrain IDE

Comment: This of all the things is what I needed to know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

Also be sure that your jest config does not have `silent: true`. In my case, I didn't realize that someone else had added that to our config.

I don't see it in the [list of config options](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration), but [the command line flag is documented here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#silent).

Answer (score 13):

Having tried a few of the config options in the previous replies, using console.debug() instead of console.log() worked.

Comment: Also works in vitest 

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me: `jest --verbose true`

Answer (score 8):

[According to the v27 docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--silent) `silent` is what you want here. `verbose false` (the default) prevents Jest from outputting the result of every test in a hierarchy while  `silent true` (the default) will:

> Prevent tests from printing messages through the console.

Use `npx jest --silent false` if you want to run Jest with that option from the CLI. Tested this just now with `console.log` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the issue was caused by [only] flag in:
`it.only()` or `test.only('some text',()=>{})`

Comment: Can you please provide more info? Where is the flag applied?

Comment: @Alireza Not really a flag, but when you do this `test.only( ... )`.  remove the only function.  See the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api)

Answer (score 5):

Tried the advice given regarding jest config settings to no avail. Instead, in my case, the issue seemed related to not awaiting asynchronous code:

```js
test("test", async () => {
  console.log("Does output")

  new Promise(resolve => {
    // some expectation depending on async code
    setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log("Does not output")) , 1)
  })
})
```

Rather, awaiting the promise does output the async log:

```js
test("test", async () => {
  console.log("Does output")

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    // some expectation depending on async code
    setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log("Does output")) , 1)
  })
})
```

Possibly related background:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441

Comment: this was my case as well. I have the console.debug right before the `expect(calls.length).toBe(1);` and only after having `await expect(calls.length).toBe(1);` the `console.debug` worked. 

Answer (score 4):

Try using console.info() which is an alias for console.log(). I tried almost all the above answers but still console.log() didn't worked for me by any means. So, used console.info() which did the work.

Answer (score 4):

On MacOS with jest version 26.6.3 I had to append `--silent="false"`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing else was working for me, not `verbose` or `runInBand` etc..  Finally I tried:

`--useStderr=true`

Even though it is a setting for errors, I was able to see `console.log('test log');` after setting this option.

Comment: This is a useful answer & solves the printing issue efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was importing the functions from the compiled version (present in `dist` folder) instead of the `src` folder. And therefore it was using the old version. So rebuilding the project and/or importing from `src` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of **November 2023** with `jest` **v. 29.7.0** you need to set the env variable `DEBUG` to `test`, like this:

```bash
DEBUG=jest npx jest -t 'my test'
```

...and it results in the test running with the `console.log` outputs, for example:

```
  console.log
    Testing redirect from /foo to /foo/bar

      at Object.log (src/index.test.js:143:15)

  console.log
    Map(21) {

(...)
```

But it's not specific to running a single test - running all of them gives the same result.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: I can't find any docs about it, @smac89... I found this suggestion here: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/8208#issuecomment-595188558

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the logs where made when the module is required, so before the start of an actual test case. Change from a top-level `import` to using `require` inside the test case fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `transform-remove-console` plugin is present in my babel.config.js

```
if (api.env() !== 'development') {
  plugins.push('transform-remove-console');
}
```

I remove the plugin and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "verbose: false" in jest.config.js

Answer (score -4):

renaming my file to `index.test.js` from `index.spec.js` did the trick for me.