# How to read console.log from a mounted component with Enzyme and Jest in Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have a component I'm mounting with Enzyme. There is an object that is defined inside the constructor of the component. I need to read values inside that object.
How do I do this?
If I was using the browser, I would use console.log(this.object.property) in the constructor or other function. In Jest, this doesn't seem to work.
I tried running console.log in my test() function by:

```
console.log(wrapper.instance().object)
```

but it only showed me the default props from the object.
My prefered way would be to see console.log anywhere in the component. Is there a way to enable that? Otherwise, what is the best way to get access to properties of rendered components in Enzyme so I can do a console.log in one of my test() functions?

Comment: Try adding `--verbose false`?
Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest

Comment: That worked, I just couldn't figure out the syntax. in package.json I updated the line for the test script to be "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose=false"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `--verbose false` will fix the issue.
The test line in package.json should look something like:
`"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose=false",`

Just like [Console.log statements output nothing at all in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest) suggested.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `console.log(wrapper.debug());`

Comment: Perfect answer you save my day