# How to display logs in jest unit test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In my package.json I have this jest test configuration:

```
 test: {
        default: `${crossEnv(
          'CI=false'
        )} react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose=false`,
        local: {
          default: 'react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage',
        },
        coverage: 'lerna exec npm start test.coverage',
        ci: `${crossEnv('CI=true')} react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage`,
  },
```

For some reason when I run a jest test and use console.log() the log is not displayed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console.log statements output nothing at all in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Jest as far as I know. What I usually do to bypass this is just `expect(valueToLog).toBe('');`

The solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2441) could work for you too.