# How can I tell Jest not to suppress console output on failure?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

It seems that some combination of `--silent=false` or maybe `--verbose=false` is needed [to get `console.log` output from Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest). But none of these options seems to help (in Jest `29.3`) when my test fails (i.e., throws an error):

```
test('console output', () => {
   console.log('this never prints')
   throw new Error('but why?!?') // or 'expect(true).toBe(false)'
})
```

Why, oh why, Jest, do you do this? A failing test is exactly when I need console (i.e. debugging) output the most.

How can I see `console.log` output regardless of whether something in the test throws an error?

Comment: Would running tests as just `node_modules\.bin\jest` work? This showed console.log output for me. Jest 29.3, Windows. package.json may have `--silent` flag, as mentioned in linked question, which prevents console output.

Comment: A fresh new environment of jest 29.3 works - [see it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-xqhqhv?file=/index.test.js). You should probably share your configs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Jest configuration file (jest.config.js)
module.exports = {
    errorOnDeprecated: true,
    verbose: true,
    forceExit: false,
};
```

The `errorOnDeprecated` option, when set to `true`, will cause Jest to throw an error whenever a deprecated feature is used. This will prevent Jest from suppressing the console output of the deprecated feature, and will allow you to see the full output of the test run.